# multiplication behavior in ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Regarding multiplication, behavior of ruby is that `24.0 * 0.1` is not `2.4`. Why does this happen?

```
24.0 * 0.1
# => 2.4000000000000004
```

Comment: Floating point math question. There are 100s of duplicates to choose from (but apparently not a good canonical one for Ruby when I just looked). In short, don't worry unless you need absolute precision (e.g. for money) in which case use a different numeric type.

Comment: A question downvote is unfair in my opinion as this question is tagged ruby.

Comment: This is [a problem every computer scientist should be aware of](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)...

Comment: I think the Ruby community on SO should construct a canonical question and answers to this often-asked question. Then closing one like this as a duplicate would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for answers. It was my white spot.

Comment: Can somebody please explain why this question was downvoted? Sure, this is a topic everybody should know about but everybody had a stage some time when this was all new to him/her. So I don't see a reason why it should not be asked.

Answer (score 2):

Only very few numbers can be represented precisely in floating point arithmetic.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point for more details.